# Cross-site scripting - ASP.NET form action being modified by URL

Tags: asp.net, webforms, xss

After running a security scan across our web application (WebInspect), it has reported several XSS vulnerabilities with some aspx pages.

The request URL seems to be able to change the form action.

Example,

```
/Website/somepage.aspx/'+alert(1234)+'
```

the form action is changed to

```
action="'+alert(1234)+'"
```

To rule out our application code, I tried this with the default new Visual Studio webform project and it allows the same.

How can this be prevented?

I've always been told that un-validated input being reflected into the page is bad news.

Comment: parameterize your variables and sanitize input

Comment: This must have to do with the rewrite rules that you have set. The `/Website/somepage.aspx/'+alert(1234)+'` must give an error page, and not convert it to `+alert(1234)+`. At least to me gives an error page not found because this part `/'+alert(1234)+'` is a new file on the url.

Comment: I do not have an variable to parameterize or validate. The url has been added to the end of the aspx page url, and it cause the page to render with the form action modified. I dont see the input as part of the query string to validate. This is happening entirely out side of my code. I have confirmed the behaviour occurs with the unchanged out of the box WebForm project type from Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: I dont have any rewrite rules. This isnt an MVC app, just a old style WebForm web application.

Comment: If you do something like /Website/somepage.aspx/foobar then "foobar" is put into the action of the form.

Answer (score 1):

just put something in the action, something like this:

```
<form id="id_form" runat="server" action="Default.aspx">
```

When the action form is not specified asp fills this attribute with which you wrote in the URL next to the last slash. If you write something there asp doesn't rewrite this.

Comment: Please explain why your code would answer the asker's question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your `global.asax - Application_Start` to see if any routes have been defined.

Comment: Not in our code, but I'm beginning to suspect that a third-party library may be doing so. Is there an easy way to see the routes defined? maybe list them out from a test page?

Comment: Hmmm.. can't say for sure.. maybe enumerating the route collection?  `Dim routeCollection AS System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection = System.Web.Routing.RouteTable.Routes`