# Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability found in Url parameter - ASP.NET form action being modified by URL

Tags: asp.net, webforms, xss

Based security scan report for our web application - Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability found in URLparameter . The following attack uses plain encoding: 22746.

For example let say web application URL is : https://example.com/default.aspx.

Now user type in browser https://example.com/default.aspx/1234 and press enter key, which falls under Cross-Site Scripting vulnerability found in Url parameter.

When I inspect the HTML tags, form action url is changed to ./1234 as below:

```
*<form id="aspnetForm" name="aspnetForm"
  method="post" action="./1234" 
  onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();">*
```

This is similar type of issue : ***[Cross-site scripting - ASP.NET form action being modified by URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431057/cross-site-scripting-asp-net-form-action-being-modified-by-url)***
But from the post not able to get specific answer.

Thanks